# ¿Como obtener los valores de DATA de un Objeto dentro de un Controlador?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo el siguiente código que a través de un controlador me trae un objeto `$resource`, esos valores no los puedo mostrar en la vista, el codigo es el siguiente:

1- El modelo

```js
'use strict';
(function (){
 'use strict'
 angular
 .module('crud')
 .factory('UsuarioModel',function($resource){
  return $resource('http://localhost/crud/laravel/index.php/',{},
  {
   update:{method:'PUT'}
  }
  );
})();
```

2- El Controlador

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';
 function UsuarioController($scope, UsuarioModel){
  var scope=this;
        scope.usuarios=UsuarioModel.get({"start":0,"limit":10});
        console.log(scope.usuarios);

 }

 angular.module('crud')
  .controller('UsuarioController', UsuarioController, ['$scope']);
})();
```

esto es lo  que me muestra la consola:
[image: el resultado del console.log]

3.- esta es la vista

```html
<tbody ng-repeat=" usuario in usuarios | filter: buscador">
     <td>{{ usuario.nombre_usuario}}</td>
     <td>{{ usuario.login_usuario }}</td>
     <td>{{ usuario.password_usuario }}</td>
     <td>{{ usuario.email_usuario }}</td>
     <td>{{ usuario.telefono_usuario }}</td>
     
     <td><a href="#/info/{{id}}"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Ver</button></a></td>
     <td><a ui-sref="edit({id})"><button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Editar</button></a></td>
     <td><a href="#/remove/{{id}}"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Eliminar</button></a></td>
    </tbody>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de como mostrar los valores del array?

Comment: A ver si entiendo, el servidor efectivamente te retorna los usuarios pero angular no los muestra en la vista?

Comment: Exacto, el servidor me manda un objeto, pero en la vista no los puedo mostrar los datos